# How can add a fd of io.open to uloop

Tags: lua, serial-port, openwrt

I am using lua on onenwrt, try to add a fd to uloop. but reports error, this is code.

```
local uloop = require "uloop"

local rserial=io.open("/dev/ttyUSB2","r")
uloop.init()

udp_ev = uloop.fd_add(rserial, function(ufd, events)
    local words = ufd:read(1)
    print(words)
end, uloop.ULOOP_READ)

uloop.run()
```

when runs it, report missing getfd method on uloop.fd_add(),

[image: 1]

so would someone please tell me how to add a block read operation to uloop?

Comment: lua version is 5.1.5

Comment: `uloop.fd_add` [expects](https://github.com/xfguo/libubox/blob/master/lua/uloop.c#L172) either fd (as a number) or userdata with `getfd` method.  In Lua `io.open` returns userdata which stores fd somewhere inside but there is no way to get it.  In other words, do not use `io.open`.  You need some other Lua library which can open a file and return its fd.

Comment: You may try to pass `0` as the first argument of `fd_add` and redirect input `lua your_program.lua </dev/ttyUSB2`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what do you mean redrict input lua your_program.lua </dev/ttyUSB2, sorry , I am not understand that.

Comment: `# lua ./test_uloop.lua </dev/ttyUSB2` - This is a command to redirect stdin to `/dev/ttyUSB2`. Inside your code use number `0` as FD of stdin (instead of `rserial`).

Comment: I modified code `local uloop = require "uloop"

-- local rserial=io.open("/dev/ttyUSB2","")
uloop.init()

udp_ev = uloop.fd_add(0, function(ufd, events)
 local words = ufd:read(1)
 print(words)
end, uloop.ULOOP_READ)

uloop.run()` It runs normal by using 'lua ./test_uloop.lua </dev/ttyUSB2', but when it receive data from ttyUSB2, report error _italic_ lua: test_uloop.lua:9: attempt to index local 'ufd' (a number value)
stack traceback:
 test_uloop.lua:9: in function <test_uloop.lua:8>
 [C]: in function 'run'
 test_uloop.lua:13: in main chunk
 [C]: ?`

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to format in comments

Comment: `udf` (the first argument of the callback) is now the number `0` (you have passed it to `fd_add`), not the file object.  You should read from stdin instead: `local words = io.read(1)`

Comment: It is impossible to format in comments except `ticks`, *single asterisk* and **double asterisk**